# C++ vectors sort ascending/descending

Tags: c++, sorting, vectors

How can I eliminate repetition from this code?

```
std::vector<std::wstring> vec;
bool                      descending;
if (descending)
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(),
              vec.end(),
              std::greater<std::wstring>());
}
else 
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(),
              vec.end(),
              std::less<std::wstring>());
}
```

I tried

```
std::sort(vec.begin(),
          vec.end(),
          descending 
             ? std::greater<std::wstring>()
             : std::less<std::wstring>());
```

but it fails because `greater` and `less` do not evaluate to the same type.

Another question: is it possible to automatically retrieve the required type, `std::wstring`, from the object `vec`?

Comment: All containers have an internal type indicating the type they contain: `vec::value_type`

Comment: @LokiAstari: MSVC++10 complains "A name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name."

Comment: See below: For value_type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways of going about this. One is creating an aggregate type that can forward to the call to the correct comparator.

```
template <typename T>
struct comp
{
private:
    bool desc;
    std::greater<T> great;
    std::less<T> less;

public:
    explicit comp(bool descending = false)
      : desc(descending)
    { }

    bool operator()(const T& f, const T& g) const
    {
        return (desc) ? great(f, g) : less(f, g);
    }
};
```

The downside of this is that a `comp` object will be at least `sizeof(greater + less + bool)`. This may or may not be a problem. Your call to sort would then look something like:

```
typedef std::wstring str_t;
bool descending = true;
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp<str_t>(descending));
```

If the decision is always known at compile time, you can play some template tricks:

```
template <typename T, bool desc>
struct comp;

template <typename T>
struct comp<T, true>
{
private:
    std::greater<T> great;

public:
    bool operator()(const T& f, const T& g) const
    {
        return great(f, g);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct comp<T, false>
{
private:
    std::less<T> less;

public:
    bool operator()(const T& f, const T& g) const
    {
        return less(f, g);
    }
};
```

This requires `descending` to be `const` or `constexpr`:

```
constexpr bool descending = false;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp<str_t, descending>());
```

This might be a one step forward, two step back kind of solution. It's quite a bit of code to avoid an `if/else` - you'll need to decide if this is worth it at all.

Edit: As @LokiAstari pointed out, you can simplify the above with inheritance:

```
template <typename T> 
struct comp<T, true>
  :  std::greater<T>
{ }

template <typename T> 
struct comp<T, false>
  : std::less<T> 
{ }
```

Comment: Last example can be simplified to: `template <typename T> struct comp<T, true>: std::greater<T> {}` and `template <typename T> struct comp<T, false>: std::less<T> {}`

Comment: @LokiAstari Good point. Added.

Answer (score 3):

not an answer but extended comment that needs space:

```
 typedef std::vector<std::wstring>   Vec;
 Vec vec;

 std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<Vec::value_type>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) seems to work here with g++ 4.5.2 and `-std=c++0x`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::function<bool(std::string,std::string)> cmp; 
  if (false)
    cmp = std::greater<std::string>();
  else
    cmp = std::less<std::string>();

  std::vector<std::string> vec = { "2", "1", "3" };
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);

  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

You can also use the ternary operator if you cast your compare objects to the same type:

```
  typedef std::function<bool(std::string,std::string)> cmp_t;
  const auto cmp =
    true ? static_cast<cmp_t>(std::greater<std::string>()) :
           static_cast<cmp_t>(std::less<std::string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a simple helper function template:

```
template<typename Iter>
void sort_with_order(Iter i0, Iter i1, bool descending)
{
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type value_type;

  if (descending)
  {
    std::sort(i0, i1, std::greater<value_type>());
  }
  else 
  {
    std::sort(i0, i1, std::less<value_type>());
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> vec;
bool                      descending;

// ...

sort_with_order(vec.begin(), vec.end(), descending);
```

Comment: Of course, this is how I did it, still not optimal.